# userid doesn't match with real users

Tags: google-analytics, userid

We have set up a user id view in GA, but it seems users data doesn't match with the real number of employees in the company. The website is an intranet and in GA there are more users than employees so we don't understand why this can be possible.

Does anyone kwow how that can be possible?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Need a bit more context. How are you setting userID? Do employees ever browse the portal using incognito? Using different browsers? etc